# How would I improve this class in terms of responsiveness and performance?

Tags: java, performance, android

I'm about to release this application as a hobby and I'm wondering how would I improve the speed of the calculations and overall responsiveness of the class?

I have covered a module briefly in data structures and algorithms so I'm thinking a big factor would be reducing the amount of loops I'm using.Can some suggest/pinpoint some improvements to the code or even a way of streamlining some of the operation? I'm thinking that I could be utilizing a better structure or design.This is the main class where the user input three calculations that are piped to a calculation.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{  

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

        /**
         * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
         */
        private Vibrator myVib;

        ViewPager mViewPager;
        EditText offsetLength,offsetDepth,ductDepth;
        Button calculate;
        //DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter;
        String getoffsetlength; 
        String getoffsetdepth; 
        String getductdepth; 

        double off1,off2,off3;

        //button filter
        PorterDuffColorFilter greenFilter =  new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final Intent intent1=new Intent(this,AboutActivity.class);
            final Intent intent2=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            offsetLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offLength);
            offsetDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offDepth);
            ductDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ductDepth);
            calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
            calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

            final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.a,null);

            // Set up your ActionBar
            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

            //button vibration
            myVib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

            // You customization
            final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar);
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));

            final Button actionBarHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
            actionBarHome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
            actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(this);
            actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {                

                   startActivity(intent2);

                }

            });
            //final Button actionBarSent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_sent);

            final Button actionBarInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_staff);
            actionBarInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_help);
            actionBarInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
            actionBarInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {                

                   startActivity(intent1);



                }

            });


            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the app.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                double marking1=2,marking2=2,marking3=2;

                if (offsetLength.getText().length() > 0 ) {
                String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
                }

                if (offsetDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
                String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
                }
                if (ductDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
                String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 
                }
                double tri1,tri2;
                //double marking1,marking2,marking3;

                // validate whether the variables are not null
                if(getoffsetlength != null){
                    double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
                }
                if(getoffsetdepth != null){
                    double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);
                }
                if(getductdepth != null){
                double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth);
                }


                marking1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(off1,2) + Math.pow(off2,2));
                tri1 = Math.atan(off2 / off1);

                tri2 = (Math.PI - tri1) / 2;
                marking2 = off3 / Math.tan(tri2);

                marking3 = marking2 * 2;


                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalcResult.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("number1", marking1);
                myIntent.putExtra("number2", marking2);
                myIntent.putExtra("number3", marking3);
                startActivity(myIntent);

                //vibrate button onClick
                myVib.vibrate(20);

                //calculate.setColorFilter(greenFilter);


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Calculating!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Must enter a numeric value!");


            }
    //      
        }

        /*
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            return true;
        }

        */

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Closing Activity")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();    
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
        }

        /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
         * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
         */
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
                // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
                // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // Show 3 total pages.
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
         * displays dummy text.
         */
        public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
            /**
             * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
             * fragment.
             */
            public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

            public DummySectionFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                        container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                        ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have any loops. As an additional comment, the repeated code in `onClick()` should be extracted into a single method that is called 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through this code I feel that there must be something missing? Does it work? Does it even compile?

For example the onClick() method  all the places I have marked are 'dead' variables... variables you declare inside a block and are not visible outside the block:

```
            double marking1=2,marking2=2,marking3=2;

            if (offsetLength.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString();  // MARK
            }

            if (offsetDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString();  // MARK 
            }
            if (ductDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString();  // MARK 
            }
            double tri1,tri2;
            //double marking1,marking2,marking3;

            // validate whether the variables are not null
            if(getoffsetlength != null){
                double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);  // MARK
            }
            if(getoffsetdepth != null){
                double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);  // MARK
            }
            if(getductdepth != null){
            double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth);  // MARK
            }
```

Then, you have:

```
            marking1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(off1,2) + Math.pow(off2,2));
            tri1 = Math.atan(off2 / off1);
```

Firstly, these should fail to compile because the variables `off1` and `off2` are not in scope. Secondly, you should be zero-checking the division to ensure there's no division-by-zero.

All in all, I think this code is non-functional.....

---

## EDIT

Ahh, I see that the variables I though were failing are actually declared at the class level, not in the method.

What this means is that your code is very buggy, and the lines I have marked above are **COMPLETELY USELESS** and have no impact on program execution....